# Loading XML using a HTTP GET request in classic ASP

Tags: xml, xslt, vbscript, asp-classic

I'm working on an old software written in classic ASP (VBScript).

I should create an asp page that makes an XSL transformation. I'm able to do this using static files but I have to work with XML files dynamically generated by asp pages (this doesn't work).

This is my code:

```vb
Dim document, stylesheet, o
Set document = Server.CreateObject("Msxml2.DOMDocument")
document.async = False

Set o = CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")
o.open "GET", "http://localhost/aaa/cgi-bin/fo/file.asp?id_x=39", False
o.send

'document.load Server.MapPath("test.xml") ' <- with static file is working
'document.loadXML(o.responseText) ' <- not working
document.load o.responseXML ' <- not working

Set stylesheet = Server.CreateObject("Msxml2.DOMDocument")
stylesheet.async = False
stylesheet.load Server.MapPath("test.xslt")

'Response.Write o.responseText ' <- working! (return the correct XML)
'Response.Write o.responseXML.xml ' <- not working (empty result)
Response.Write document.transformNode(stylesheet)

Set document = Nothing
Set stylesheet = Nothing
```

All is running on a virtual machine with Windows 2000 Server (unfortunately I need to do this in this way).

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem. It was a tricky error.

Asp reads from a database in which the chars are encoded using ISO-8859-1.

The generated XML contained an attribute with an accented character (`name="unità"`).
When I loaded the page my `responseText` contained `name="unit?` (the last `"` was 
surprisingly cutted off). So I was working with a malformed XML document very similar to the correct document.

For this reason it printed the `responseText` but not the `responseXML`.

I solved it changing database values directly, using url encoding for special chars.

Comment: If it was encoded wrong it would be malformed, that's what happens when you mis-match encoding. But as you didn't provide that information how do you expect us to second guess. Glad you managed to fix your problem, next time though be more descriptive.

Comment: Sorry but I didn't think that could be an encoding problem. I discovered it later. Thanks for your time.

Comment: What I meant was if you had provided as a minimum this `Asp reads from a database in which the chars are encoded using ISO-8859-1.` then you might have got a more accurate answer.

Answer (score 1):

This is a quick stab (untested).

Based on what you already have, I've made minor changes. You don't need to declare your `Msxml2.DOMDocument` object, by using `Set document = o.responseXML` you get the same effect. Added a HTTP Status code check to capture any issues.

Looking at this line;

```
document.load o.responseXML
```

This will not work because the `Load()` method expects a file location.

```vb
Dim document, stylesheet, o

'Should be using the IServerXMLHTTPRequest object
Set o = Server.CreateObject("MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP.6.0")
With o
  Call .Open("GET", "http://localhost/aaa/cgi-bin/fo/file.asp?id_x=39", False)
  Call .setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/xml; charset=utf-8")
  Call .Send()
  If .Status = 200 Then
     Set document = o.responseXML
  Else
    'Handle errors
  End If
End With

Set stylesheet = Server.CreateObject("Msxml2.DOMDocument")
stylesheet.async = False
stylesheet.load Server.MapPath("test.xslt")

Response.Write document.transformNode(stylesheet)

Set document = Nothing
Set stylesheet = Nothing
```

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers Indeed it might, but as I'm at work and time is limited just made some quick changes to the OP's code to try and help him out. Will pad out the answer when I get 5 minutes, if it helps I'm happy.

Comment: Thank you for your answer but it was only a problem of encoding (I post my answer too). Moreover I can't install MSXML 6.0 on that machine so I can't execute the line `Server.CreateObject("MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP.6.0")`.

Comment: @xonya No problem, the version of `MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP` doesn't matter just use the one you have installed, I just used `6.0` because it's most recent.

Answer (score 1):

Lankymart's answer will probably work, but here's a tried and tested example I've used before with the Bing API

```
<%
    Option Explicit
    Dim xml, xsl    

    Set xml = Server.CreateObject("Msxml2.ServerXMLHTTP.6.0")
    xml.open "GET","http://www.yourxmlsource.com", false, "myUid", "myPassword"
    xml.send 
    Response.ContentType = "application/xml"

    Set xsl = Server.CreateObject("Msxml2.DomDocument.6.0")
    xsl.load(Server.Mappath("yourxslfile.xsl"))

    response.write xml.responseXML.transformNode(xsl)

    Set xsl = Nothing
    Set xml = Nothing
%>
```

If you don't need to send login information to get your XML then you may not actually need to use get.  Here's what I use for RSS feeds

```
<% 
  dim xml, xsl
  set xml = Server.CreateObject("Msxml2.DomDocument.6.0")
  xml.setProperty "ServerHTTPRequest", true
  xml.async = false
  xml.validateOnParse = false
  xml.load("http://rssurl.com")

  set xsl = Server.CreateObject("Msxml2.DomDocument.6.0")
  xsl.load(Server.Mappath("rss.xsl"))
  Response.Write(xml.transformNode(xsl))
  set xsl = nothing
  set xml = nothing 
%>
```

Comment: Like the use of `xml.setProperty "ServerHTTPRequest", true`.

Comment: @Lankymart - As long as you're pulling XML.  `Msxml2.ServerXMLHTTP` objects are useful in other situations, eg if you want to include html or json from an external url

Comment: Thank you for your answer but it was only a problem of encoding (I post my answer too). Moreover I can't install MSXML 6.0 on that machine so I can't execute the line `Server.CreateObject("MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP.6.0")`.

Comment: @xonya - you got it to work, that's the main thing.  Re msxml6, I tend to assume people are using IIS7 or above which has it installed out of the box, but if you're on an old server you can drop the `.6.0` from all the server.createobject commands in my examples and they'll use msxml3 instead